# Pandas. A pretty way to delete cell and shift left others in row?

Tags: python, pandas

In dataframe I need to delete some cells and shift left others in row :

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({'X0':['anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext'],
                 'X1':['12:40','boss','engen','15:44','16:01'],
                 'X2':['anytext','12:44','14:06','anytext','anytext'],
                 'X3':['anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext']})

 df
  
        X0     X1       X2       X3
0  anytext  12:40  anytext  anytext
1  anytext   boss    12:44  anytext
2  anytext  engen    14:06  anytext
3  anytext  15:44  anytext  anytext
4  anytext  16:01  anytext  anytext
```

I want to delete "boss" and "engen"  and shift left other cells in row:

```
        X0     X1       X2       X3
0  anytext  12:40  anytext  anytext
1  anytext  12:44  anytext      NaN
2  anytext  14:06  anytext      NaN
3  anytext  15:44  anytext  anytext
4  anytext  16:01  anytext  anytext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need select rows for shifting, e.g. here is tested if first 2 values in `X1` are numeric by `str[:2]` and [`Series.str.isnumeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html), invert mask by `~`, so only for non numeric value use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
m = ~df['X1'].str[:2].str.isnumeric()
```

Another idea for mask, thank you @Manakin is test if datetimes in format `HH:MM`:

```
m = pd.to_datetime(df['X1'],format='%H:%M',errors='coerce').isna()
```

Also if want test numeric 2 numbers with `:` with length `2`:

```
m = ~df['X1'].str.contains('^\d{2}:\d{2}$')
```

---

```
df[m] = df[m].shift(-1, axis=1)
print(df)
      X1       X2       X3
0  12:40  anytext  anytext
1  12:44  anytext      NaN
2  14:06  anytext      NaN
3  15:44  anytext  anytext
4  16:01  anytext  anytext
```

If need modify all columns after `X1` one idea:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'X0':['anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext'],
                 'X1':['12:40','boss','engen','15:44','16:01'],
                 'X2':['anytext','12:44','14:06','anytext','anytext'],
                 'X3':['anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext']}) 

m = ~df['X1'].str.contains('^\d{2}:\d{2}$')
df.loc[m, 'X1':] =df.loc[m, 'X1':].shift(-1, axis=1)
print(df)
       X0     X1       X2       X3
0  anytext  12:40  anytext  anytext
1  anytext  12:44  anytext      NaN
2  anytext  14:06  anytext      NaN
3  anytext  15:44  anytext  anytext
4  anytext  16:01  anytext  anytext
```

Another with convert `X0` to index:

```
df = df.set_index('X0')
m = ~df['X1'].str.contains('^\d{2}:\d{2}$')
df[m] = df[m].shift(-1, axis=1)
df = df.reset_index()
print(df)
        X0     X1       X2       X3
0  anytext  12:40  anytext  anytext
1  anytext  12:44  anytext      NaN
2  anytext  14:06  anytext      NaN
3  anytext  15:44  anytext  anytext
4  anytext  16:01  anytext  anytext
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['X1'],format='%H:%M',errors='coerce').isnull()` may be more efficient i think?  rather than evaluating them as `str` then `int`

Comment: @Manakin - Here better matched data, so better in my opinion

Comment: I think str.contains (regexp)  is more pretty!

Comment: But, what can I do if I don't want to modify left column X0? 
                                                                                                     

df=pd.DataFrame({'X0':['anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext'],
                 'X1':['12:40','boss','engen','15:44','16:01'],
                 'X2':['anytext','12:44','14:06','anytext','anytext'],
                 'X3':['anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext','anytext']})

Comment: @MaximSheludyakov - Then use `df.loc[m, 'X1':] =df.loc[m, 'X1':].shift(-1, axis=1)`

Comment: jezrael "df.loc" it is fine!  I will modify initial question

Comment: @MaximSheludyakov - Super, added to answer.

Comment: another question: If I found  "boss" in column, how I can  delete the cell and other right cells in row?

Comment: @MaximSheludyakov - Try `df.loc[df['X1'].eq('boss'), 'X1':] = np.nan`